# What is the word for starting to do things the people you live with do?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I was told I was nice because I was Canadian. I wanted to say "I am not Canadian, but maybe I have learnt being nice after living in Canada for a while". I came up with this sentence, but I believe "take" and "habit" might not be the best words to use. What can I use instead?

> Maybe after years of living in Canada, I have *taken* that *habit*.

Comment: You could say, "Maybe after years of living in Canada, I have **been assimilated**."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say that you have **taken on** the habit or **adopted** the habit or just that you have **learned** the habit.

There is nothing wrong with *habit*, but you could also say "I've learned to do things the Canadian way" or "I've adopted the Canadian way of doing things".

Answer (score 2):

I would say in everyday language:

**I've gotten into the habit of** being nice.

to get into the habit of doing something.= idiom

[British English: I've got into the habit of being nice.]